# PackageMaker Qt4

Tags: macos, qt, qt4, installation, packagemaker

I'm having a problem with Qt4 in PackageMaker. After generating the installer, I tested it in a virtual machine, but I'm getting one problem, QtGui is not recognized by the other program.  As if it would not be installed.

I tried to use aliases pointing to QtGui original, but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For information on how to deploy a Qt application on Max OS X I recommend the following resource: [Deploying an Application on Mac OS X](http://doc.qt.digia.com/main-snapshot/deployment-mac.html)